Irreducibility under etale ring map
Let $A\rightarrow B$ be a etale ring map between finite type algebra over algebraically closed field $k$.
If $A$ is one dimensional integral domain, is $B$ direct product of finite type integral domain over $k$?
I know if $A$ is normal and integral domain, then $B$ is direct product of integral domain.
And I know scheme theoretic analog is false that is there exists morphsim  $X\rightarrow Y$ between finite type schemes over $k$ where $Y$ is irreducible  and $X$ is connected but not irreducible.
(Look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2035396/irreducibility-of-schemes-under-etale-morphism)

No, take $X$ to be a nodal cubic, then for every integer $d\ge 1$, $X$ has a connected finite etale cover $Y_d$ of degree $d$, which is obtained by gluing together $d$ copies of $\mathbb{P}^1$ in a chain (a "Néron polygon"). Under the map $f : Y_d\rightarrow X$, all of the intersection points in $Y_d$ map to the node in $X$.
Now take $U = \text{Spec }A$ to be any affine open neighborhood of the node in $X$. Then $f^{-1}(U)$ is affine and étale over $U$, but not irreducible.
E.g., you can take $U = \text{Spec }k[x,y]/(y^2-x^3-x^2)$, in which case $f^{-1}(U) = \text{Spec }B$ is a bunch of affine lines glued in a chain. Each affine line is the normalization of $U$, and you can write down an explicit $B$ by taking a suitable fiber product of rings (see, e.g., Stacks 0E25).
To add some flavor: In the true theorem you cited, normality (as with most notions of smoothness/regularity) ascends along etale morphisms, and prevents situations where connected components can fail to be irreducible, which is exactly what happens in the example above.
